# Hook Up a Delegate from other WindowForm Control

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Is it possible to use the same delegate in other class?

I would like to implement the same delegate in other control without copy code... Can I link this delegate to my object?

I did try this:

```
public MyOtherControl(Control OtherControl)
  : base()
{

  EventInfo _combo_key_press_event;
  Type _combo_key_press_delegate;


  _combo_key_press_event = this.GetType().GetEvent("KeyPress");
   // KeyPressEventHandler  
  _combo_key_press_delegate = _combo_key_press_event.EventHandlerType;     

  MethodInfo miHandler = OtherControl.GetType().GetMethod("OnKeyPress",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.CreateInstance);

  Delegate.CreateDelegate(_combo_key_press_delegate, this, miHandler);

}
```

Yet, all time I get an ArgumentException saying `Error binding to target method`.

Comment: What you are trying to implement? Why reflection?

Comment: You can only use Delegate.CreateDelegate to target static methods. Please elaborate on what are you trying to do. Chances are all you need is to add an extra parameter to pass the delegate you want.

Comment: Delegate is just a type like as classes, I don't think there is any kind of hook here, unless you mean you want to add a Delegate to a class (as its inner/nested type), some kind of dynamic delegate?

Comment: The Control.OnKeyPress() method is *not* suitable to act as a KeyPress event handler.  It has the wrong signature.  And it **raises** the KeyPress event.  So what you are trying to do would always generate a StackOverflowException.